# Creating database and setting privilege in MySql dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, server, cpanel

Is there a way to create a database on the online server dynamically where you can create the user and set the privilege from there it self.
i tried creating a database on my cpannel dynamically using php but it shows a error message of access denied. It only shows up a option to create the database statically and allocate the rights to a particular user.
this thing is to be done in PHP.

Comment: You have to provide privileges to user been used to connect to database in PHP. Grant access to that particular user.

Comment: my question is how to create the database dynamically and then set the privilege to the user already created.

Comment: You have to use MySql commands in query in PHP for creating the database and setting the privileges.

Comment: i have tried it and it is not working. Is there any example or sample code available with you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use MySql commands in query in PHP for creating the database and setting the privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this solution for creating Database in CPANEL.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76339678/3775083